# How can OS actually measure the CPU power?

Tags: linux, kernel

Currently I think that processor only has two states: run and not run. If it's running, it will use its full power to process a task. If there are multiple processes, processes will be shared by a portion of CPU.

How can the computing power can be divided into "portions"? So, suppose a CPU has 1 million transistors, only half of the transistors are used if the CPU is only at 50%?

Or is this related to allocated processing time for each process? i.e.  assume "100%" means a process seizes a CPU for 200 milliseconds, if a process with a default nice value (priority value) 0, which means the process will receive 50% computing power or, in other word, 100 milliseconds. What is the correct idea?

Comment: Recent processors can also change their clock frequencies, and some can switch off or slow down individual cores. And I heard that some very recent chips have even some circuits measuring the current. And many of them are able to measure their temperature.

Comment: You might want to clarify the word "power" in your question and indicate the places where it is meant to indicate *energy* (joules/second) or *resources* (instructions/second).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain this on the example of Intel x86 CPUs and Windows NT (and its derivatives). One of the built-in system processes on these OSes is the *System Idle Process*. This process represents how much CPU time is utilized by the operating system's "idle loop". That idle loop does nothing else but executes the `HLT` instruction of the CPU. That instruction, in turn, commands the CPU to do nothing until the next interrupt arrives.

Therefore, if the scheduler decides that there are no processes that require CPU time at the given moment, it is given to the *System Idle Process*. If, say, 99% of the time in the last *n* seconds was spent by "executing" that process, it means that the CPU was really utilized only in 1% in these *n* seconds.

I believe it is totally analogous with Linux, only that it doesn't have a separate process to model the "idleness" of the CPU.

On a side note : it is, of course, possible, to have a OS that doesn't execute the `HLT` instruction at all. That was the case with Windows 98 and earlier (including, obviously, MS-DOS), whose idle loop simply consisted of a `jmp $`. That caused the CPU to use much more power.

Comment: The idle thread in Windows also checks if there are any pending DPCs and delivers them. As for DOS, simply because it wasn't a multitasking OS and it didn't really control program execution, yielding the CPU to other programs was nonexistent by definition. At the same time, implementing that lacking functionality (a scheduler and threads) in programs and/or sprinkling `hlt` here and there and hoping nothing would break wasn't very practical, it complicated programs. So, most programmers naturally chose to consume all CPU cycles even while their program was doing nothing. And it was OK.

Comment: So, the CPU actually executes at full power or halt (idle). The power is measured by the CPU usage over a period of time. Is this `n` seconds you are talking about the limit of all processes? For example, the OS measures the CPU every 200 milliseconds, so the maximum numbers of the processes which can share the CPU is 200, each with 1 milliseconds. And on the other hand, during this period all processes not always can consume 200 ms simply because of process priority,isn't it?